# Node-red Dashboard UI doesn't show Tab Name

Tags: dashboard, node-red

Could anybody explain me why the Node-red dashboard doesn't show the Tab title on head for the selected menu item?
I am very basic node-red user so I do not have UI templates or complex things on the flows.

For the example should show Home.

I am using `Raspberry PI` with:

**Raspbian Release**

```
NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux 9 (stretch)"
VERSION="9 (stretch)"
Node-red Release: 0.19.5
Node-red dashboard Release: 2.11.0
```

[image: picture]

Comment: Good question, I am having the same issue.  You can also get support on the node-red forum https://discourse.nodered.org/